# MySQL 5.5 vs 5.6: Are there any Magento 1.9 benchmarks?

Tags: mysql

Since there are mixed results floating around the web regarding performance of Mysql 5.6, I was wondering if anyone has tested it with both 5.5 and 5.6 and noticed any differences?

Answer (score 1):

While we don't have an official benchmark, we have seen MySQL 5.6 indeed performing slightly slower than MySQL 5.5 in real life usage.

I wouldn't recommend using MySQL 5.6 for now unless you need Magento 2 (as that is the minimum requirement) as MySQL 5.5 should be good enough for Magento 1.9.x.